# Macro that runs a macro if cell returns an error

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run a macro that decides whether to run another macro or leave the spreadsheet as is.  If activecell.offset(3,0).value is an error, then run SubMac_3. If not an error, then leave as is.

```
Sub SubMacIfError()
    IfError ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value then
        SubMac_3
        SubMac3
    Else
        ActiveCell.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds a bit overkill, can't you just create your own custom function for the formula being used in cell activecell.offset(3,0)? That way that custom function can do the logic necessary, versus creating an entirely new macro handling the error.

Comment: `If IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value) Then SubMac3`

Comment: `If IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value) Then Call SubMac_3`

Answer (score 2):

Updated to add Tim Williams comment (to the question), since that line of code is a bit cleaner.

```
Sub SubMacIfError()

'If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(3)) Then
If IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(3).Value) Then

    SubMac_3

Else

    ActiveCell.Select

End If

End Sub
```

As another general note, I would stay away from `.Select` and `ActiveCell` unless you absolutely need that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for every worksheet in the workbook AT THE INSTANT A CELL IS SELECTED then use this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsError(Target(4)) Then SubMac_3
End Sub
```